# How do I run node.js code after I installed it with xampp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xampp

I run xampp and I was recently told by a friend to try node.js as a replacement for PHP so I thought I should give it a try

I went to node.js's website and installed the .msi file, later I put the following code in a .js file

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

I launched xampp and executed "node app.js" from the command prompt, tried visiting localhost:1337 from my browser but it cannot resolve

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This code works for me.

Comment: @Andy when I try to run it from command prompt it outputs a windows host script error, error: object unexpected

Comment: Try `node.exe app.js`.

Comment: XAMPP has nothing to do with node.js

Comment: @Andy it doesn't recognize node.exe, I checked my enviroment variables and the path to the node installation is added so just node should work, but it isn't. apparently the error is in the first character of the first line

Comment: Erm, have you tried turning it off and on again? Otherwise I've got nothing, sorry.

Comment: What does running just `node` get you?